# SQL connect two DATE and TIME fields

Tags: mysql

As quickly and efficiently connect the two fields DATE (YYYY-MM-DD) and TIME (00:00:00) database into one field DATE-TIME (DATETIME). I have many tables and I want to do it quickly and without errors.

Comment: Do you want to concatenate two fields in the resultset of a query, or do you want to alter every table in your database that has a date and a time field to contain a single, combined field? Please give more details.

Comment: thank you for a minus, I wish you a good day/ or night.

Comment: The purpose of downvoting is to inform other users of poor-quality questions and to give you an incentive to improve yours (they can, after all, be removed). Please try not to take it personally.

Answer (score 2):

```
CONCAT(`date_field`, ' ', `time_field`)
```

Comment: I was tninking about hard rebuild the dbase, but your way is fantastic. thnks.

Comment: @Andrew `CONCAT()` returns a string, you might consider using `CAST(<src> AS DATETIME)` if you need it to be a proper `DATETIME`. Reworking the database might still be a good idea, if you need indices and the like, but you can use this in that process as well. Glad I could help.